# How to Insert a Calculated ROW Into a Pivot Table Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

Anyone have an idea? Would love to solve this mystery! I can't believe I can't find this anywhere so must be doing something stupid, but so be it.

Problem: How do you insert a calculated ROW into a pivot table in Google sheets?

In my example, I have a pivot table of financial data across multiple properties. There are rows for Income and Expenses by property (simplified for example), with the properties as columns.

I want to insert ROWS (not columns!) into the pivot table to calculate KPIs like Profit (= Income - Expense). (There are more complicated calculations but simplifying here for sake of example).

I know how to insert a Calculated Field, which provides a COLUMN with the specified formula. However, I can't figure out how to insert a calculated field that produces a ROW with a specified formula.

Example below.

Thank you in advance!
Kim

Database:

[image]

Pivot Table:
[image]

In the pivot table example above, I would want to add two calculated rows:

1. The first would calculate the Net Operating Income (= Income Total - Expense Total)
2. The second would calculate the Cash Flow (= Net Operating Income - Other Expense Total).

Comment: Could you provide an example. Here I don't understand why you need pivot instead of a simple new row which compute the diference between two line (Income, Expense)

Comment: @FrédéricLOYER Example has been added above, thanks!

Comment: i also couldn't find it, i think there's no calculated row in google sheet. i can't believe it, it's so important. there's only calculated field, which is, adding a column, not a row

Answer (score -1):

You can use **calculated item** to create custom rows in the pivot table.

i.e. click on pivot table> go to PivotTable Analyze>Fields, Fields, Items & Sets>Calculated Item

Then create custom row for Net Operating income and in the value something like = 'Late Fees' + 'Rent' - 'Repairs'... etc
Then another row for Cash Flow  = 'Net Operating Income' - 'Other Expense Total'

Comment: Are you talking about Excel or Google Sheets? I don't see any option for calculated item in Google sheets.

Comment: @KimHopkins in Pivot table editor - values - ButtonAdd- top row.

Comment: there's no calculated row in google sheets, only in excel.