# How to Reference a Column \by Header Name Using Data Set Named Range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges, chatgpt-api

See example below. Suppose you have a data set in Google Sheets and you've created a named range from it, called `DataRange`. Suppose a column header is called `Properties`. ChatGPT claims you can reference that column using the named range and the column name, i.e. `DataRange[Properties]`. ChatGPT claimed I can use this to reference ranges in the SUMIF formulas for example, and also suggested I test the functionality with the formula:

`=column(DataRange[Properties])`

Every way I've tried to experiment with this generates a *formula parse error* and I can't find any reference to this functionality online. I don't think this works.

What say you?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit info on whats the end goal you envision whilst applying this `DataRange[Properties]`?!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I thought there was a policy about not answering questions of the form "I got this from an AI and it doesn't work"

Comment: There are multiple ways you can work with specific columns from a named range, however it would depend on your use case. Can you provide more details or an example of what you are trying to do specifically or what your main goal is?

Answer (score 0):

`DataRange[Properties]` looks suspiciously like the syntax of the structured references enabled by Excel's Tables feature, which does not exist in Google Sheets. You could potentially consider using the obscure 'D' functions (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/173497?sjid=1321726078039769391-EU) to get close to what you're trying to achieve, for instance `=dsum(DataRange,"Properties",[criteria])`.

Answer (score 0):

WEll, I'm pretty sure this syntax doesn't exist in Google Sheets but just to close the loop, the workaround I came up with is to give the columns named ranges instead of the above.

As an aside, it didn't help with my problem. I'm trying to create a pivot table  (picture below) with calculated ROWS for things like Profit (:=Income - Expense), but now that I've got my profit row, I can't figure out how to pivot in any way that makes sense to accomplish this. Urgh.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's my link where I posted my original problem, but no replies as of yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76017369/how-to-insert-a-calculated-row-into-a-pivot-table-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment134070689_76017369